# How do I disable keyboard shortcuts that switch tty's (on Ubuntu GNOME)?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, tty, wayland, gnome-shell

I've installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, and there's one slight annoyance. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> I get moved to `tty1`, and when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> I get moved to `tty4` - which were not what those shortcuts usually do.

I'm guessing that I'm running Wayland now and that that has something to do with it? Is there any way I can disable this?

Please note that I do not want to disable the tty's themselves - I'd like to still be able to reach them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> like before. I merely want to disable these new shortcuts.

Comment: `tty` is the correct term :)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I've updated the post to clarify that I do _not_ want to disable the tty's themselves, just the new shortcut for getting to them.

Comment: Oh and I also just noticed that all answers to the other question assume X.org.

Comment: I think those are your options, pick your poison. If editing xorg.conf does not fix the problem either file a bug report, file a feature request, or disable.